# Using TikZ to draw a block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to build a simple block diagram using TikZ but haven't been successful. With some help from previous posts I have been able to get close to what I need. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=rinput] (rinput) {};
    \node [sum, right of=rinput] (sum1) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum1] (controller) {$K(s)$};
    \node [block, above of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (up){$H(s)$};
    \node [block, below of=controller,node distance=1.3cm] (rate) {$G(s)$};
    \node [sum, right of=controller,node distance=2cm] (sum2) {};
    \node [output, right of=sum2, node distance=2cm] (output) {};
    \draw [->] (rinput) -- node{$U(s)$} (sum1);
    \draw [->] (sum1) --node[name=z,anchor=north]{} (controller);
    \draw [->] (sum2) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
    \draw [->] (z) |- (rate);
    \draw [->] (rate) -| (sum2);
    \draw [->] (z) |- (up);
    \draw [->] (up) -| (sum2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The issue is that I am trying to get rid of the K(s) block as well as sum1 (where U(s) goes). Basically I want to directly connect the H(s) and G(s) blocks and have U(s) going to the center of that line. 
I am having difficulty removing K(s) since the other two blocks are defined in terms of K(s).
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Why not use `above right` and `below right`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is exactly the output you're looking for, but with a `tikz matrix` you don't have to worry about where to position the nodes, TikZ does it for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
        block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
        tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
        sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate},
        output/.style= {coordinate},
        pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \matrix[column sep=2cm, row sep=.7cm] {%
            &\node [block] (up) {$H(s)$};\\
            \node [input] (rinput) {}; & \node[input] (sum1) {}; & \node [sum] (sum2) {}; & \node[output] (output) {};
            \\
            &\node [block] (rate) {$G(s)$};\\
        };  
        \draw [->] (rinput) -- node[above] {$U(s)$} (sum1);
        \draw (up) -- (rate);
        \draw [->] (sum2) -- node[above] {$Y(s)$} (output);
        \draw [->] (rate) -| (sum2);
        \draw [->] (up) -| (sum2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, please note that you have loaded `tikz` twice in your MWE, and from the TikZ manual, para. 16.1:

> Remark: The libraries arrows and arrows.spaced are deprecated. Use
>   arrows.meta instead/additionally, which allows you to do all that the
>   old libraries offered, plus much more.

I've used `arrows.meta` with `latex` but, of course you can choose what you like.